# Diagonal dominance versus positive semi-definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

I know that for a symmetric matrix $A$, diagonal dominance, i.e. $$A_{ii} \ge \sum\limits_{j \ne i} |A_{ij}|$$ implies positive semi-definiteness.

How about the other way? Does positive semi-definiteness imply diagonal dominance? Could you point to a proof or a counter example?

Comment: I think you want $A_{ii} \ge \sum_{j \ne i} |A_{ij}|$ (without absolute values on the $A_{ii}$).

Comment: Whats wrong with the square matrix $J$ i.e., having all its entries $1$ ?

Comment: Yes, Robert. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick counter example

```
>>> a=2*ones(3,3)+eye(3)
a =

   3   2   2
   2   3   2
   2   2   3

>>> eig(a)
ans =

   1.00000
   1.00000
   7.00000
```

Comment: $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}3&2\\2& 3\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ will also do - its eigenvalues are $1$ and $5$.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: but that one _does_ have diagonal dominance.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh, my bad! Sorry - blunder!

Answer (score 1):

A $2 \times 2$ counterexample is $\pmatrix{a^2 & a\cr a & 1\cr}$ for $|a| \ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following matrix:

$$
A=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1  \\
 0 & 0  \\
 \end{array} } \right]
$$

Notice that $A$ is positive semidefinite (it has a double eigenvalue at $\lambda=0$). But it is not diagonally dominant since $0=|A_{11}|<|A_{12}|=1$

Comment: Did the same mistake, $A$ is assumed to be symmetric :)

Comment: The Question was: "Does positive semi-definiteness imply diagonal dominance?" But, you're right...

Answer (score 0):

You can see link http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/srgbk/node16.html
In that link, the author said that if ma trix symmetric and stricly diagonal dominant then A positve define.